# dynamically create JSON array with .each()

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to create a JSON array dynamically.  In the site, there are a dynamic number of <div id="#selected">'s and I need to take all of their values and create a JSON array.

I've come across the .push() functionality, but I have not been able to figure it out.

```
<!-- there could be a million of these, or only one... each value is unique though -->
<div id="selected" value="5|3"></div>
<div id="selected" value="3|65"></div>


function json_array_selected() {

var JSon = {};
$('div#selected').each(function() {
        // let's first split the given values
        var Split = $(this).attr('value');
        Split = Split.split('|');
        var Type = Split[0];
        Value = Split[1];

        // now let's set up our Json array... using the value = type way, there should never be
        // any repeating 
        JSon.Value = Type;

});
return JSon;
}
```

Comment: Ids should be unique so `$('div#selected')` will only get you one element

Comment: even if I do a loop with .each()?

Comment: Actually it does work http://jsfiddle.net/Ldm7U/, but Ids should still be unique

Comment: If your ids aren't unique your html is invalid so even if it works as in Musa's fiddle I wouldn't count on it working in _all_ browsers. Much better to use a class attribute to group similar elements. Also note that what you are creating is not JSON and not an array, it is simply an "object". (JSON is a _string_ representation of data that happens to be in a format that looks like JS object literal syntax.)

Comment: how would I go about doing it via string then?  I understand what JSON is more or less but I'm at a little loss as to HOW to make JSON dynamically via Jquery / JS

Comment: If you need JSON because, e.g., you will be passing the data to the server via an Ajax request, then you'd start with an object as you are already doing and create any required properties, then use `JSON.stringify(yourObject)` to convert it to a JSON string as the final step before sending the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of

```
JSon.Value = Type;
```

try with

```
JSon[Value] = Type;
```

or you will always overwrite a key named "Value"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot have two nodes in HTML with same id. You will have to assign some class for those `div` tags. For example -

```
&lt;div class="selected" value="5|3">&lt;/div>
&lt;div class="selected" value="3|65">&lt;/div>
```

I tried following piece of code on jsfiddle.net

```
function json_array_selected() {
  var JSon = {};
  $('div.selected').each(function() {
    // let's first split the given values
    var Split = $(this).attr('value');
    Split = Split.split('|');
    var Type = Split[0];
    Value = Split[1];
    JSon[Value] = Type;
  });
  return JSon;
}
var res = json_array_selected();
alert(JSON.stringify(res));
alert(res["3"]);
```

Resulting JSON array is

```
{"3":"5","65":"3"}
```

Comment: How would you write the code if you had multiple identical Value objects and didn't want them to be overwritten? For instance if you have "3|65" and "3|75", you'll overwrite the former.